C# Excel Interop - Using Sensitivity Labels
I've created an application that automates the editing of .XLSX files using the Excel Interop and then saves the files.
However, my organization's policies require applying a sensitivity label to these files, which triggers a popup (see image below).
The issue is:

If I set EnableEvents to true in the Excel COM object, the popup blocks the process.
If I set EnableEvents to false, the popup is bypassed, but the files are not saved successfully.

I'm looking for a way to handle or bypass this popup so the process runs smoothly without manual intervention.
Has anyone encountered this issue before, or does anyone have suggestions on how to resolve it? Thanks in advance for your help!
Excel Sensitivity Label Popup
Already tried:

Saving in other formats, like .XLS, .XLSM
Using LabelInfo, SensitivityLabel

More information:

Visual Studio 2022

.NET Framework 4.7.2

Already tried this, but it does not work on .NET Framework.



This question is similar to: How to programmatically set Excel Sensitivity Labels using C#, Microsoft.Interop.Excel?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thanks Serg! I updated the question. As stated in the provided question, that solution does not work on .NET Framework.

I have no Excel installed, so can't check the solution myself, but technically the solution looks like the "clear COM" and it should not depend on .net version. Try to access the mentioned SensitivityLabel via the dynamic keyword (so, late binding via the IDispatchEx will be used during the runtime).

The following may be of interest: Does my version of Office support sensitivity labels and Subscription and licensing requirements for sensitivity labels
